# EF Core scaffold DbContext for old Oracle database

Tags: oracle11g, entity-framework-core

I have an old Oracle Database (11.2.0.4.0) that I would like to scaffold using EF Core 6.4.4 and Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore 6.21.61.

The scaffolding command I use is:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "User Id=User;Password=Pass;Data Source=Inst;" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir Models -Context MyTestContext -ContextDir . -force -Tables Table1, Table2 ...
```

It does a great job about the entities themself, but it does not recognize the relations between tables.

When scaffolding is done, I can set compatibility through `UseOracleSQLCompatibility`, but I am not aware of a way to tell scaffolding about compatibility.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.LogTo(message => Debug.WriteLine(message));

            optionsBuilder.UseOracle("User Id=User;Password=Pass;Data Source=Inst;",
                b => b.UseOracleSQLCompatibility("11"));
        }
    }
```

When doing a

```
  var master = db.MasterEntities.Where(m => m.MasterId == 1)
      .Include(m => m.Details).ToList();
```

it returns a list with one master, all properties correctly filled, but with no details.
The SQL debug info sent to the debug window only is about querying the master table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was not the scaffolding.

The problem was `.Include`

There was a

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

where there needed to be a

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```